# Need to archive teamcity build configuration of test

Tags: configuration, teamcity, archive

please help me! i need to archive the configuration of one test, not the hole project, how can i do this! i can archive only the hole project not a test, but need to archive the config of test! Teamcity 8.0.1!

Comment: i've tried only teamcity instruments! administration---->projects---->at the right side MORE-----> archivation! but it's only for the whole project, not for one test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have to archive only one configuration of build, you have to create the new one project  , copy config of your build to your new project, and after that: administration->projects->on your project at the right side click on more and archive this project!